# how does Webcam stream is usually done?

Tags: streaming, webcam, theory

I am currently doing a small project and one of the components is to capture the webcam stream from one side to the other (Client-->Server). right now i have the stream from the Server as bytes and as far as i know i should transfer these bytes using UDP. My question is how to do that,

- is it should be enclosed into a file and then transferred?
- should i transfer the raw bytes?
- should i create a buffer at the client side and when it gets full show it on the screen?

in short i would like to know how to implement the transfer of the stream from the server to the client (i need just on side).

Answer (score 1):

You can stream a webcam to a client via multiple ways.

use Windows media Server/ Flash media Server. Push your webcam to the server by Windows Media Encoder or flash media encoder, and use the server live link to playback on the client(windows /Web).

Use Windows Media Encoder to stream your webcam to anyone without a server involved. when your encoder starts, you will get a URL to view your stream, which you can use to playback on the client(windows /Web).

use third party streaming services, where they give you a publishing point to publish your webcam stream, and use the link provided by them to playback on the client(windows /Web).. (check with brighcove or Mogulus by LiveStream

Hope this helps.